# Image not complete. How to callback and load the image? Draw function inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

```
draw() {
        if (this.finalXPos > (-canvas.width) && this.finalXPos < canvas.width) { //render image
            if (this.base_image.complete) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.base_image, this.finalXPos, this.yPos, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
            else {
                console.log('IMG BACKGROUND ' + this.base_image.src + ' NOT COMPLETE');
               //WHAT TO DO?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's better to load the image before starting to draw anything. `window.onload = draw`

Answer (score 1):

If [Image.complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete) is `false` then the loading is still in progress. There is no need to attempt to reload the image. You can just check `complete` again next frame,

WARNING `Image.complete` will be `true` when the loading has completed, but that does not mean the image is available for render as any errors while loading will `complete` the image loading process.

Ideally you should listen to the Image events (`load` and or `error`) so you can be sure that it can be rendered.

An alternative semaphore to indicate the image is ready to render would also be much better than using the  `Image.complete` semaphore

```
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
var canRenderImage;  // undefined

const img = new Image;
img.src = "??????";
img.addEventListener("load", () => canRenderImage  = true, {once: true});    
img.addEventListener("error", () => canRenderImage  = false, {once: true});



function renderLoop() {
    if (canRenderImage) {  // is it safe to render the image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (canRenderImage === false) {
        ...
        // what ever the plan is when there is missing content
        ...
    } // else image is not complete try again next frame

    ... code

    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```